# How to edit one-to-one related model in an admin tab

Tags: relationship, silverstripe

How can I present a one-to-one related object for editing in the *same* admin, as a new tab?

I have two models related one-to-one: Lorem and Ipsum. Each declares a `$has_one` relationship with the other.

There is a LoremAdmin that declares `$managed_models = array('Lorem' => […])`. Should that also include `'Ipsum'`, to have the same admin manage the related model too?

The LoremAdmin currently presents only a select field (on its “main” tab) for *existing* `Ipsum` instances. Instead, I want:

- Creating a `Lorem` also creates an `Ipsum`.
- The “main” tab contains nothing about `Ipsum`; instead, all the `Ipsum` fields are on an `Ipsum` tab of the LoremAdmin.

How can I convince the LoremAdmin to do that?

(The site is using [SilverStripe 3](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/), if it matters.)

Comment: Have you try this one [silverstripe-hasonefield](https://github.com/silvershop/silverstripe-hasonefield/tree/1) ?